# how to set image object into image src if html is created dynamically via loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my vuejs code i have created two method the handleFileChange method save images objects in an array and the displayImageOptions create dynamic html with that uploaded images

When i upload images the html is not rendered correctly

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of how to handle this situation...?

```js
data() {
    return {
      files: [], // In this array i have store the images objects
      frame: 0,
      baseUrl: window.BreakOut.baseUrl
    }
  },
  handleFileChange(e, index) {

    let myFilesLength = this.files.length
    myFilesLength += 1
    if (myFilesLength == index) {

      this.files.push(e.target.files[0])
      this.displayImageOptions(this.files)
    } else {
      let html = '<div class="modal-cont"><h4>Please insert image in sequence.' +
        '</h4><div class="alert__icon"><span></span></div></div>'
      Swal.fire({
        customClass: {
          popup: 'error-modal',
        },
        html: html,
        showCloseButton: true,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
      })
    }
    console.log(this.files)
  },
  displayImageOptions(imageFiles = []) {

    let html = ''
    if (!_.isEmpty(imageFiles)) {

      _.forEach(imageFiles, (index, image) => {

        html += '<div class="number__select-box">'
        html += '<div class="number__select-inr">'
        html += '<a href="javascript:;" class="custom-images" data-number="' + index + '">'
        html += '<h2>'
        html += '<img src="' + image + '">'
        html += '</h2>'
        html += '</a>'
        html += '</div>'
        html += '</div>'
      })

    } else {

      for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {

        html += '<div class="number__select-box">'
        html += '<div class="number__select-inr">'
        html += '<a href="javascript:;" class="custom-images" data-number="' + i + '">'
        html += '<h2>'
        html += '<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">'
        html += '</h2>'
        html += '</a>'
        html += '</div>'
        html += '</div>'
      }
    }
    return html
  },
```

This is the code where user upload images

```
 <div class="custom-drag-wrapper">
          <div class="avatar-upload" v-for="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" :key="i">
                <div class="avatar-preview">
                    <input 
                        type='file' 
                        class="imageUpload" 
                        name="custom_image"
                        @change="handleFileChange($event, i)" 
                        accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"/>
                    <span class="custom--count">{{i}}</span>
                    <img class="imagePreview" :src="defaultImagePreviewUrl"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here I have renderdynamically created HTML with images

```
<div class="select-your-lock">
                <h3>SELECT THE SYMBOLS THAT WILL OPEN THE LOCK</h3>
                <div class="tabs--custom__select" v-html="displayImageOptions"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Apart from the image issue, why not use VUE to loop the HTML instead of lodash  - or at least use normal JavaScript forEach. Your code does not need another framework when vanilla JS OR the vue framework can do the job

Comment: Is `image` a source string or a callback here? `_.forEach(imageFiles, (index, image)`

Comment: sir, actually I have a very complex scenario the img render code is written in jquery. my front-end developer don't know vuejs as much that I know so when user click on element I user @change="handleFileChange($event, i)" to call my function that is responsible to store images object into array to store that images in the database

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting file names, it may have problem with image asset path.

Check if your files are loaded from correct asset location. Check for any 404 errors in network tab.
This will help you debug problem further.

Comment: Images loaded successfully i shown it below from where i upload it